# How to use Vim as Git editor without "cannot allocate color" errors

Tags: bash, vim

(I've found a few proposed solutions for this problem, but none of them work for me.)

**Problem**

I am trying to use Vim as the git core.editor -- no matter what I do, I get "cannot allocate color" messages.

I've tried setting the git core.editor (using --replace-all) to vim, mvim, vim -U NONE -u NONE, mvim -u NONE -U NONE, etc.

**Notes**

- I have nothing referring to Vim in my .bashrc
- I have a `/usr/bin/vim` that is aliased to `/usr/bin/vim -> /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim`
- I have no aliases for vim or mvim set
- If I execute vim in the terminal it exhibits the same problem
- echo $TERM responds `xterm-256color`

**Environment**

Vim Version:

```
IM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Sep  1 2012 18:08:47)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-646
```

OS: `OS X 10.8.2`

Bash: `GNU bash, version 4.2.39(2)-release (i386-apple-darwin12.2.1)`

Comment: Do you have in your .vimrc `set t_Co=256`?

Comment: I just tried adding that but still getting the same errors.

Comment: Symlinking or aliasing `/usr/bin/vim` to anything else is a very bad idea. How and when do you get that error? Is it a bash error or a vim error? Does it have a number?

Answer (score 0):

This is `E254`:

```
The color name {name} is unknown. See gui-colors for a list of colors that 
are available on most systems.
```

Do you, by any chance, expect a GUI-only colorscheme to work in a terminal? What colorscheme do you use?

Comment: Thanks, but I was not. [After trying various configuration] when I just launched Vim in the terminal it worked fine with no color errors...this only came up when I tried to use it for Git commit messages and continued, no matter the configuration of the options I used when assigning it as core.editor ... and it works now with the new Vim. I have no idea why.

Comment: It looks like a symlinking issue.

Comment: Quite possible! As usual with Brew, I think, I did the step of `Brew link`. My reference to Vim being "wrong" was rhetorical and I probably shouldn't have said it that way. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to the problem: rather than using the original Vim that comes with OS X or the MacVim snapshot installer, I installed Vim with Brew and now everything works the way it should with no changes.

Frustrating to know that the settings I had many many revisions ago were actually right; Vim was wrong (which is the only time I've ever been smarter than Vim).

Comment: If I had a better answer, I would tell you. I deleted the MacVim snapshot binaries, used Brew to compile and install Vim, and my existing setup worked with no other changes. Not sure what else to say.

Comment: "rather than using the original Vim that comes with OS X or the MacVim snapshot installer, I installed Vim with Brew and now everything works the way it should with no changes" - I had the exact opposite problem. I had minor issues with MacVim, so I installed brew vim, and pointed the soft links /usr/bin/vi and /usr/bin/vim at it. It now doesn't work at all, and I can't remember what the original soft links pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa does not play nice when invoking the binary found in

```
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim
```

MacVim ships with a startup shell script to solve this problem.
If you simply drag and drop MacVim.app as usual into /Applications then copy the associated `mvim` startup script into your local binary folder:

```
/usr/local/bin/mvim
```

then a simple symbolic link to alias vim to MacVim:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/mvim /usr/local/bin/vim
```

should solve the problem :)